# Can not connect with a simple http server(tcp connection) on oracle compute instance(oci), ssh connection works well

Tags: oracle, server, instance

I am using oracle cloud to create a http server for learning , so I am new on this. Thank you for your any help!

**Instance information**

```
Image: Canonical-Ubuntu-20.04-2022.02.15-0
Shape: VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro
```

**Have added ingress rule on subnet(7500 port):
[Picture of subnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hFEE.png)**

```
Source      IP Protocol Source Port Range Destination Port Range  Allows 
0.0.0.0/0   TCP         All                7500                   TCP traffic for ports: 7500
```

**Using python to create a http server:**

```
python3 -m http.server 7500 &
```

**It was showing：**

```
ubuntu@tcp-server:~$ Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 7500 (http://0.0.0.0:7500/) ...
```

Calling `lsof -i` returns

```
COMMAND    PID            USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python3   1806            root    3u  IPv4  33281      0t0  TCP *:7500 (LISTEN)
```

**Allowed 7500 port on ufw:**

```
ufw Status: active

To                          Action        From
                  
7500                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
7500 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

But I can not visit public_Ip_address:7500.

**Using telnet:**

```
sudo telnet 152.69.123.118 7500
```

**Returns:**

```
Trying 152.69.123.118...
```

and does not connect

**Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 1):

The reason is from iptables setting:

sudo nano  /etc/iptables/rules.v4

add this sentence:
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 7500 -j ACCEPT

then:

sudo su

iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4

Done!

ubuntu image from oci has been modified by oracle, the default setting has limitted ports accepted.
Therefor we have to open the port manually.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the problem was the oracles linux's firewall, you can solve the issue running this command:

```bash
firewall-cmd --add-service=http --permanent
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some important attributes you need to be aware of when using a fresh ubuntu image on oci. For the sake of this discussion firewall and [iptables](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/iptables/iptables.8.en.html) are synonymous
By default

1. there are 4 chains standard INPUT, FORWARD, OUTPUT and  InstanceServices
2. OUTPUT will have 1 rule

```
InstanceServices  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            169.254.0.0/16
```

InstanceServices destination 169.254.XXX.YYY point to oci services like bootvolume ect ...

3. FORWARD rejects all
4. Your default INPUT chain will look like

```
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4    ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:123
5    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22
6    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

this allows ssh and udp port 123 for NTP only

create a rule for port 7500 and place it with the existing tcp rule for ssh

```
sudo iptables -I  INPUT 6  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7500 -j ACCEPT
```

now INPUT chain is

```
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4    ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:123
5    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22
6    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:7500
7    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

as long as we have the correct VCN route table entries, Security list entries or network security group entries for tcp 7500 you can get thru the instance firewall to destination port 7500

**Notes**
Its really import not to delete the InstanceServices rule in the OUTPUT chain AND not to delete the InstanceServices chain
This can happen if you are new to iptables and you do something like

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
```

Its worth it to learn iptables however [firewalld](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-cmd.html) is easier.
Oci does not recommend [ufw](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ufw.8.html)

Your iptable rules will not [survive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84781/iptables-resets-when-server-reboots) a reboot unless you persist them

these issues are well documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Compute/References/bestpracticescompute.htm) under subheading `Essential Firewall Rules`